# JPQL between dates

Tags: sql

I have a database table which has two columns `DATE_START` and `DATE_END`.

Now I want to find all entries where a `Date` is between `DATE_START` and `DATE_END`.

Example:

`ID | DATE_START | DATE END
 1  | 2015-1-1   | 2015-1-10`

Lets say i want to query with `MYDATE = 2015-1-5` then I would like the database to return row number `1`

I tried the following query:

`select * from table where DATE_START >= MYDATE and DATE_END <= MYDATE`

However this does not return the row because `DATE_START` will not match

Comment: The code you tried is wrong. The `>=` and `<=` should be switched. Your `MYDATE` will only match if its outside the interval wich will never happend ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE MYDATE BETWEEN DATE_START AND DATE_END;
```

Read more http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways
Either by using `Between` As

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE MYDATE BETWEEN DATE_START AND DATE_END
```

Or also can do it using

```
SELECT *
    FROM your_table
    WHERE MYDATE >= DATE_START AND MYDATE <= DATE_END
```

Using `Between` is a proper way to do it